# How can I nest an array in an array attribute in dynamodb putitem

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following code to place an item in a table in dynamoDb it works fine. I want to nest an array in an array. For example, for the attribute 'color1' I want to make "A" to be array of items. How can I do that

```
$result = $client->putItem(array(
            'TableName' => 'usr',
            'Item' => array(
            'email'      => array('S'=>$_POST['email']),
            'first'    => array('S'=>$_POST['firstname']),
            'country'    => array('S'=>$_POST['country']),
            'last'   => array('S'=>$_POST['lastname']),
            'password' => array('S'=>$hashedpassword),
            'list'=> array('SS'=> array("1", "2", "3")),
            'color1'=> array('SS'=> array("A", "2", "5")),
            'phonenumber' =>array('S'=>$_POST['phonenumber']))

        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact same way you're doing it for the outer `SS` array; with mapping:

```
$result = $client->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'usr',
    'Item' => array(
        'email' => array('S' => $_POST['email']),
        'first' => array('S' => $_POST['firstname']),
        'country' => array('S' => $_POST['country']),
        'last' => array('S' => $_POST['lastname']),
        'password' => array('S' => $hashedpassword),
        'list' => array('SS '=> array("1", "2", "3")),
        'color1' => array('SS' => array("A" => array('1', '2'), "2", "5")),
        'phonenumber' => array('S' => $_POST['phonenumber'])
    )
));
```

Comment: It works absolutely fine, as you can see [**here**](https://3v4l.org/qsYcU) (where I've substituted `$hashedpassword` and your `$_POST` variables for `'a'`). The problem is either in your `$_POST` (you should really check that each value is set), your `$hashedpassword`, or the function you are calling on `$client`.

Comment: interesting. I tried it with dynamodb and there is an error. I will look into it further thanks anyway